# delete multiple fields for a key in Redis

Tags: python, redis

I have the dictionary that is as follows:

```
dict1 = {"a":"foo","b":"bar","c":"foobar"}
```

The keys of dict1 are fields of a key in redis. I want to use  **hdel**  to delete those fields in Redis. I was wondering if its possible to send multiple fields at once to redis.

I thought of creating a list of keys from dict1 and passing it to redis.hdel but it doesn't work and I am always returned false. Will appretiate any help/suggestions.

```
list1 = []
key = "somerediskey"
    for k in dict1:
        list1.append(k)
data = redis_connection.hdel(key, list1)
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The Python redis lib accept an `hdel(name, *keys)`, so you should do:

```
data = redis_connection.hdel(key, *list1)
```

Also, you don't need to create a list of keys, you can just use `dict1.keys()`:

```
key = "somerediskey"
data = redis_connection.hdel(key, *dict1.keys())
```

Related docs: http://kushal.fedorapeople.org/redis-py/html/api.html#redis.StrictRedis.hdel

Comment: Thanks alot for your input and making code even much simpler. If I use your proposed solution, then what will be they way to get dict keys. all but one particular?

Comment: You can remove a particular key: `d = dict1.keys();d.remove('yourkey')`